# Java EE 7 SDK with JDK Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: linux, jakarta-ee, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-server

I am trying to install Java EE 7 SDK with JDK as see downloaded from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-7-sdk-with-jdk-u45-2066865.html)

I am getting this error:
"**Can't connect to X11 winder server using '0' as the value of the variable**"

as this is a server, I don't want to have a GUI. Is there there no other way to install this without a GUI for Ubuntu Server 12.04 ?

I am trying to get glassfish 4.0 up and working on here ultimately, with a My-Sql Cluster setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and install Glassfish as described on https://glassfish.java.net/download.html

It is just unzipping a file.